# Create new website from old one

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website created with Entity Framework and LINQ, and I modified the model a little bit and changed the names of the tables and relations so it would look better while coding.
Now I want to create a new website using this structure.

But if I copy the DB.edmx and DB.Designer.cs to the new project, I won't have the tables mapped to the database.

The only solution would be to delete the tables and update model again, but I don't want to do that because I would lose all my modifications to the model, and my code structure would generate errors, since I don't have for example db.Products, I would have db.products (-> the actual name of the table in the database).

How can I make a new project from an old project so that I would keep most of its functionality, only change the views and have a good to go website?

Comment: What error are you getting (if any)?  Also, how are you instantiating your `DataContext`?  Are you passing in a connection string, or are you using the default, hard-coded connection string?

Comment: The problem is that i cant update anymore the model, if i update it i lose the mappings and i get: table Products is not mapped. If i dont update i cant get my new tables that i need for the new project. I use conn string from webconfig

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the "right" way to do this, but this is what I've done for websites based on a template that includes the database/model.

I generate scripts to recreate the database, and save that as part of the project template. Then I run that script on the 'new' database, and modify the configuration for the EF connection in the new project to point to the new database.

I don't do any chances between these steps; this assures that EF sees the "same" database at its 'new' location, and everything should work fine from there. Again, provided you make no changes in the meantime. (you can change things afterward, and refresh the model thereafter)